# how to make JMenu's FocusEvent not a Temporary one?

Tags: java, swing

In Java Swing, the FocusEvent from JMenu is a Temporary type. When we check e.isTempoary() in a focusLost() method, the result is true. How can we override this default behavior to make it return false?

For example, I have a small program with a text field, a menu, and a button. The text field displays a default value of 30. the text field is a FocusListener and in its focusLost method, it will check if the e.isTemporary is true or not. If it is true, it will nothing, otherwise, it will display the default value.

After the program is running, you can change the default value to whatever you want. Then when you click the button, the default value will come back. But when you click the menu after you changed the default value, the default value will not come back. The reason is that the FocusEvent from the menu is a temporary event. How can we make it permanent?

The running program is this:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MenuLookDemo
{
    JPanel panel;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    int value = 30;

    public JMenuBar createMenuBar()
    {
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu menu, submenu;
        JMenuItem menuItem;

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("A text-only menu item", KeyEvent.VK_T);

        return menuBar;
    }

    public Container createContentPane()
    {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);

        panel = new JPanel();

        JTextField txtTest = new JTextField("" + value);
        txtTest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));
        panel.add(txtTest);

        txtTest.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("focusLost: called isTemporary()=" + e.isTemporary());
                if (e.isTemporary())
                {
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("focusLost: show value");
                txtTest.setText("" + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("focusGained:");
            }
        });

        JButton btnTest = new JButton("Click Me");
        panel.add(btnTest);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return contentPane;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuLookDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MenuLookDemo demo = new MenuLookDemo();
        frame.setJMenuBar(demo.createMenuBar());
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setSize(450, 260);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                MenuLookDemo.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I need the result that when Menu is clicked, the default value is restored in the JTextField. This is from a big project and I have some other cases that need the isTemporay() checking.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. What you are describing is, that you actually want to reset the default value either way? So why not just omit the check for `isTemporary()` and always reset the default value on `focusLost()`?

Comment: I have a big project and I have some other cases that need the isTemporay() checking. I need the result that when Menu is clicked, the default value is restored in the JTextField.

Comment: Sounds like it would suffice to have an `ActionListener` on the menu, which handles the reset of the `JTextField` on click of the menu? Or you simply reset the `JTextField` everytime you lose the focus on it.

Comment: Yes, ActionListener and other Events are possible but it is not easy to put them in place (because they are at different modules).  The FocusEvent is the easiest one if possible.